# How to create a newrelic_alert_muting_rule that covers all day on weekends?

Tags: terraform, newrelic

I want to create a [newrelic_alert_muting_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/newrelic/newrelic/2.38.0/docs/resources/alert_muting_rule) resource to cover all day on weekends, so I've written the following schedule:

```
schedule {
  time_zone          = "Europe/London"
  repeat             = "WEEKLY"
  weekly_repeat_days = ["SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"]
}
```

Could someone confirm whether that's the correct way to create a muting rule that covers all day?

Comment: Why dont you just try it and if you get errors then let us know

Comment: the schedule you've written will mute alerts on Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, for organisational structure reasons. I can't run the Terraform thing on my machine.